# Beautifulsoup returning NaN

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Please, Could someone help me, Beautifulsoup does not return timestamp of the site, only NaN, the page code is

```
<div id="1740-el" data-start="1683754200000" data-end="1683756000000" data-left="6660" class="cell-item "
```

the return:

```
<div class="cell-item" data-end="NaN" data-left="6660" data-end="NaN" id="300-ab"
```

where timestamp does not appear, I've tried with Selenium, but NaN always appears. Could anyone help me with this issue. thanks...

I try this

complete code...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

headers = {'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) Chrome/112.0.5615.138'}

url = requests.get("https://www.claro.com.br/tv-por-assinatura/programacao/grade")

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all('div', 'cell-item')

print(data)
```

Where return NaN, I expected to receive the timestamp but it doesn't..

Comment: The data you want probably depends on javascript, and `requests` does not understand javascript.  Selenium should have worked.  Can you show that code?

Comment: Solved thanks with the code to friend Biarys...tks.